# Is there a way to install all rubygems on system `gem` (1.8) to `gem19`?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, freebsd

We have a FreeBSD server which has a bunch of gems installed. Gems on FreeBSD are finicky, and Bundler isn't working on the machine.

I have two questions, both would likely solve my problem. Given another system that has `gem19` gems installed, can we package them without using using a Gemfile? (There is bundler but no gemfile)?

Or I'd like to get `gem19` to install all gems already installed on the system installed with `gem` which is Ruby 1.8.

Comment: You can use `gem list --no-version` to get a list of the gems on one machine, redirect that output to a file, then copy the file to the other and run  `xargs gem install --conservative < list_of_gems` which will then load the current versions of those into your current system. Ruby 1.8 is extremely old so I hope part of this task is upgrading to Ruby 2.2+. Or, use that list of gems to seed your Gemfile. You can even drop `--no-version` if you want to maintain the same versions across both machines, but again that can cause problems because of old versions, bugs, exploits, etc.

Comment: Very cool. Unfortunately one of the issues I'm having is that our computer is not able to connect to rubygems, and so I need to be able to take the files that are currently in the gems folder and add them to gem19

Comment: Hey @theTinMan I was curious, if both systems are identical same chipset, OS, ruby variables. Is there a downside to copying the `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/` folder between one that has all gems and one that doesn't?

Comment: None that I know of; It seems like it'd work if everything is equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was simply doing an `rsync` computer **A** with the gems, and **B** which needed the gems.

I used:
`scp A:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9 /1.9_A` then `sudo rsync -avr 1.9_A B:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9`

`-a` archive mode, archive mode allows copying files recursively and it also preserves symbolic links, file permissions, user & group ownerships and timestamps

`-v` verbose, lists changes (not needed)

`-r` recursive, I found this is actually redundant when combined with `-a` option.